# Is using 1:n + n:1 between the same tables bad design?

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, database-design

Imagine a table 1 "Event" contains event-information but you want to give users the opportunity to mark one date out of several dates as selected (because there are several opinions of which date is correct). So the dates would actually be stored in table 2 "Event".

Of course there needs to be a n:1 relationship between the tables "Event" to "Date" so multiple dates per event are possible. But is it good practices to also add an 1:n relationship from "Event" to "Date" to store the currently selected date for that "Event"-record?

An alternative would obviously be to store a flag in table "Date" ("Selected"), but I think that would be not as fast for read access on the "Event" table. Especially in LINQ2SQL it would be really easy to access the date information if there is a 1:n relationship.

(I don't want to additionally store the actual "selected" date values in the "Event" table because of the maintenance - You have to handle it manually if a different "prefered" date is selected and there are about 6 date fields to handle all kinds of date-information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Firstly, I certainly hope your tables are not named `Table1` and `Table2`. Try to be specific with the table named in your question, if possible*)

No, this is not a bad idea, and your requirements can be easily represented with only primary and foreign keys. This is a problem that's encountered quite often, where you have a 1:n relationship between a parent and child table, but there's a requirement that you have a single child that has a particular attribute. For instance, many CRM systems allow multiple addresses per customer, but only one address can be defined as the primary address.

The simplest scenario is this:

```
Event
------------
EventID
...etc.
Primary Key (EventID)

EventDate
-----------
EventID
Date
Primary Key (EventID, Date)
Foreign Key (EventID) references Event (EventID)
```

Then, once those tables exist, add a nullable `SelectedDate` column to `Event`, and make a foreign key constraint on `Event` that references `EventDate` using `EventID` and `SelectedDate`

Comment: I bow to you sir for being able to come up with a lucid answer to this question.

Comment: It should be noted that Event.SelectedDate needs to nullable otherwise you create a PerformanceDBA-like Chicken-and-Egg problem.

Comment: @Adam: Would you generally prefer this table layout, or would you consider using a flag-column (selected) in the Dates-Table to be also a viable solution?

Comment: @fnx Normalization would prefer it to be in the Event table, since all events would have a selected date, but not all dates will be selected (sparse data).

Comment: @fnx: I would use this model. The alternative (a flag) is difficult to maintain, and whether or not a date is selected is more closely related to the event than to the date.

Comment: @fnx,@Adam - In addition, you have to jump through hoops to guarantee that there is one and only one selected date for a given event if you use a flag. The only real alternative to Adam's solution is a separate table that store the selected date for each event.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, which is essentially just moving the nullable column to 6NF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is bad design. You should have a table of events, and a table of dates, and a m:n mapping table between them instead.

Comment: Unless there is either a predefined list of dates or additional non-event-related data that needs to be stored with a date, there is no need for a table for individual dates. Additionally, this does not address the OP's requirement for a single "selected" date for an event.

Comment: @Adam: Perhaps -- I'm honestly very confused by the question itself -- it's written extremely poorly. The root of the question I see here is that an event must be associated with multiple dates, and he needs fast lookup of things either by event or by date. Your answer is probably better than this one. +1

Comment: It could definitely use some improvement. What I gathered from it was the user has a table for events, and each event can have multiple dates associated with it, but only one of those dates can be "selected".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You may (or may not) place a unique constraint on `UserID, EventID` in the `UserSchedule` table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a data model goes it is not "bad" or incorrect if it's an accurate description of the reality you are trying to represent. Unfortunately SQL DBMSs have trouble enforcing cyclical constraints of this kind. To get it done in SQL you will usually have to compromise - typically by creating an extra table to represent the relationship between Event and Date.